# Locate folders with find that match a regular expression with optional groups

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to `find` files within a hierarchy whose paths contain language codes such as `de-DE` and `fr`.

I am using:

```
find srcfldr -regex "*/[a-z][a-z](-[A-Z][A-Z])?*" -regextype posix-extended
```

but it is not finding folders such as `/e/myfolder/srcfldr/langs/de`.

I've also tried:

```
find srcfldr -wholename "*/[a-z][a-z](-[A-Z][A-Z])?*" -regextype posix-extended
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually went with:

```
find "/home/ubuntu/testsrc" | grep -E "*values/[a-z][a-z](-[A-Z][A-Z])?*"
```

Piping to `grep -E` also then allowed me to use other more sophisticated regular expressions.